# Translate my Url Angular 2 - Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, url, translate

Angular2 - TypeScript - ng-Translate

Hello people,

I need to change the rest of my url depending on language selected "en/soybean", "fr/soya". In my app.routes I got this path :

```
{ path: ':lang/soybean', component: SoybeanComponent }
```

My SoyBean component is translate from the lang param with ng-translate

```
this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
   translate.use(params['lang']);
})
```

How can I display the url as fr/soya but still use path fr/soybean !?

**What I tried**

*I create a new path: `{ path: ':lang/soya', component: SoybeanComponent },`
I thought I could redirect the user to the good path :

```
 if(params['lang'] === 'en'){
       this.router.navigateByUrl('lang/soybean');
    }
    if(params['lang'] === 'fr'){
       this.router.navigateByUrl('lang/soya');
    }
```

but it will result on a infinite loading.
Then I thought I could hardcode the lang param after redirecting like :

```
if(params['lang'] === 'en'){
       this.router.navigateByUrl('en/soybean');
    }
    if(params['lang'] === 'fr'){
       this.router.navigateByUrl('fr/soya');
    }
```

but in this case I will catch an exception.*

Comment: It looks like you are treating `lang` as both a route parameter and as a constant path route?

Comment: `lang` determine witch language I will use, but it didn't change the path. If `lang` is fr then soybean.html and soybean.component will be translate to french. What I want is how can I display the url as fr/soya but still use path fr/soybean ! 

Sorry for bad explanation I will edit my first post !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my own solution with location.replace(newUrl)

I create a new path : `{ path: ':lang/soya', component: SoybeanComponent }`

and in my component I use location.replace(url)

```
 this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
            translate.use(params['lang']);
            switch (params['lang']) {
                case 'en':
                    location.replace(`index.html#/${params['lang']}/soybean`)
                        break;
                case 'fr':
                    location.replace(`index.html#/${params['lang']}/soya`);
                        break;
            }

        })
```

This works for me ! If you know a better solution i'll be glad to hear it ! Thx !

Answer (score 1):

You are overcomplicating it :-).
Just used template strings with backticks

```
url = `${lang}/${i18name}`
```

Comment: Is this angular 2 ? And could you precise where and how you use it ! Cause I define my url in the app.routes.ts like that  { path: ':lang/soybean', component: SoybeanComponent } ? thx !

Comment: Well it's baked into Typescript that's the foundation Angular 2 & 4 are based upon. https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/template-strings.html